# Should my portfolio have a personality or it should look general

Tags: portfolio

I concerned that having certain type of personality, ie. certain type of design and showcased work would put off potential clients as they would think i am not the person they are looking for.

For example, Suppose I can make most of the other designs as web designer but I can also make web designs geared toward kids specifically well. If I make my portfolio to represent that then it's for sure not going to be a hit with clients looking for e-commerce web design.

In that case should i a) make site geared toward my speciality and hope others will see potential anyway. b) make my site general based on percentage of where my business come from. c) make a new portfolio...

if c, how are you suppose to handle 3 portfolios... Doesn't it hurt your popularity as now you have 3 yous to promote.

Answer (score 2):

When presenting to fellow designers (for job interviews and the like) all that matters is that your designs are appropriate for the client.

When presenting to clients, however, as you hint at, ideally your work reflects the type of work they are looking for.

It's certainly fine/common to have many versions of your portfolio. In fact, you may want to create a unique portfolio for each and every client.

Answer (score 0):

In Architecture school they taught us to wear muted colors, ideally gray or black, while presenting. Why? Because it goes with everything.

My advice would be to create a website for adults but showcase projects that cover your broad range. Be sure to include some process and background information on the projects too.

Then I would say it might be beneficial to have one "full portfolio" and one "youth oriented portfolio" in print. For the "youth oriented" clients that you meet with, bring the portfolio specific for them. Everyone else bring the full that has a bit of both worlds in it.

Comment: While I can't disagree that black goes with everything, I also can't imagine a situation where a client would think "We can't go with this person...his shirt didn't match the cover of his portfolio!" :)

Comment: @DA01 While presenting as in, presentation boards of plans/sections/elevations pinned up and having to to stand in front of it explaining every detail. Not sitting down presenting a portfolio.

Comment: I suppose, but still sounds like silly advice, though. Granted it worked for Steve Jobs, so I guess that's enough proof...

Comment: @DA01 would you use a really bright green as the background on your website?

Comment: if it made sense, sure.